# Sending RMI stub over UDP

Tags: java, udp, rmi

I wish to send RMI stubs over UDP, only I have no idea how to create a new DatagramPacket on the sender and reconstitute the stub from the array returned from DatagramPacket.getData() on the receiver. How, for instance, can I reliably calculate the size of the packet?

Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks,

Owen.

Comment: Calculate the size of the packet where? Are RMI stubs really serializable?

Comment: I just want to send a stub over UDP, so the receiver can then call remote methods as the client to the sender as the server.

Comment: That's not what I asked. I haven't used RMI in over 10 years or so, and I'm not at all that stubs are serializable (which would mean that you can't send them anywhere). Do you need help with RMI, UDP or both? If both, then this is too broad.

Comment: Well, okay... I need to send an RMI stub from one host to another. Apparently (because this observation appears as part of my question) one needs to calculate the size of the packet (or at least its data) so one may reliably reconstitute the stub on the receiver. I need help with my problem: sending an RMI stub over UDP to another computer...

Comment: Well, how are you turning the stub into bytes? Measure the size of the resulting `byte[]` and there's your packet's data size.

Comment: How do I turn the stub into bytes? How do I get the size of the stub so I can be sure I have all of it?

Comment: Maybe you should read more about RMI. I'm pretty sure that you're approaching this whole task completely wrong. Where did you get the idea for sending stubs over UDP?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/codebase.html) is something that you're looking for.

Comment: That wasn't what I was looking for, but your tip has given me other ideas about what I will need to do soonish in terms of exchanging code units as a kind of "plasmid" from one device to another. So thanks for that too.

Comment: Possibly you are looking for the Jini Lookup & Discovery Service.

Comment: Possibly... although now I remember that I investigated the code base mechanism as a way to transmit these plasmids, and I passed on it because it involves a third server. I actually want to transmit code directly between two devices. Maybe Jini offers something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(stub);
oos.close();
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(bytes, 0, bytes.length, target, port);
// etc ... send this datagram
```

and at the receiver, the converse of this process, which I will leave as an exercise for the reader.

But my first question is 'why?' Why aren't you using the RMI Registry as the designers intended? Or RMI itself? You don't need UDP here.

NB RMI stubs are indeed serializable, which is the foundation of the Registry.

Comment: Indeed they are (now that I refreshed my memory a bit), it's been a while since I've had to do RMI, but the whole scenario sounded so wrong.

Comment: @EJP Thanks. That seems to be what I need. I'll do that and get back to you.

Comment: As for why, well this follows from the question you answered for me before: I want to multicast a UDP packet from one device to a cluster of other devices so the receivers can decide amongst themselves which one of them will engage the sender through the supplied stub. A registry will not work for multicasting will it?

Comment: I have ticked this answer because it appears to have given me what is necessary to implement my solution. However, I haven't gotten my implementation working, and so I'm still searching for an answer here. I'll probably ask another question...

Comment: Searching for an answer to *what*? I answered the question you asked. If you have another question by all means ask it, but your comment here seems entirely out of place.

Comment: I have fulfilled my promise to get back to you. To labour this point for a short while longer, I was thanking you in writing for providing an  answer to my question. Indeed, if I have another question to ask (which I think I do), I will ask it separately from this one. This question is closed. Sincerely, thank you; you have earned a reputation in my mind for offering valuable assistance being that you have regularly been a font of assistance. I hope I have conveyed this value adequately and I hope that there will be more helpful assistance to come.